# How to disable cross communicate between pods which are in 2 different namespaces in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I have 2 namespaces and 1 pod, 1 service running in each.

Example

```
Namespace 1: default
Pod: pod1
Service: pod1service

Namespace 2: test
Pod: pod1
Service: pod1service
```

I can actually make HTTP request from namespace2 pod to namespace1 pod.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://pod1service.default.svc.cluster.local/some/api
```

How do i disable communication between 2 differet namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure [network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/networkpolicies/). For that to work you also need to use a [network addon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/) that supports policies.

Comment: Also https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/declare-network-policy/ provides for a concrete example