# Istio ingressgateway 503 upstream errors when only allow mTLS traffic

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am using Istio 1.8.0 with on-prem k8s v1.19..We have several microservices running where I am using `STRICT` mode for peerauthentication. And I can verify that if I use `PERMISSIVE` mode I did not receive any 503 errors.

[image: Network console]

I really get stuck to find any solution cause I do not want to use `PERMISSIVE` mode as recommended.

Here is the log for istio ingressgateway.

```
$kubectl logs -f istio-ingressgateway-75496c97df-44g6l -n istio-system
[2021-01-16T07:28:51.852Z] "GET /config HTTP/1.1" 503 URX "-" 0 95 57 57 "95.0.145.40,10.6.0.21" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" "foo-bar.example.com" "10.6.25.34:3000" outbound|80||oneapihub-ui-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local 10.6.5.216:46364 10.6.5.216:8080 10.6.0.21:14387 - -
```

Here is the log for my ui microservice.. I did not catch any 503 errors for rest of services

```
$ kubectl get ns --show-labels
NAME              STATUS   AGE     LABELS 
hub-dev           Active   2d19h   istio-injection=enabled
istio-system      Active   3d5h    istio-injection=disabled

$ kubectl get pods -n hub-dev
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
oneapihub-api-dev-79dff67cdb-hx754       3/3     Running   0          15h
oneapihub-auth-dev-76cfcb6cb4-74ljq      3/3     Running   0          15h
oneapihub-backend-dev-d76799bcd-bmwjn    2/2     Running   0          15h
oneapihub-cronjob-dev-6879dbf9b8-wvpnp   3/3     Running   0          15h
oneapihub-mp-dev-864794d446-cfqj7        3/3     Running   0          15h
oneapihub-ui-dev-67d7bb6779-8z4xt        2/2     Running   0          14h
redis-hub-master-0                       2/2     Running   0          15h

$ kubectl logs -f oneapihub-ui-dev-67d7bb6779-8z4xt -n hub-dev -c istio-proxy
[2021-01-15T14:17:24.698Z] "GET /config HTTP/1.1" 503 URX "-" 0 95 65 64 "95.0.145.40,10.6.0.19" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" "foo-bar.example.com" "10.6.25.241:3000" outbound|80||oneapihub-ui-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local 10.6.5.216:37584 10.6.5.216:8080 10.6.0.19:31138 - -
[2021-01-15T14:17:24.817Z]
```

Here is peerauthentication

```
$ kubectl get peerauthentication -n istio-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
  kind: PeerAuthentication
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"security.istio.io/v1beta1","kind":"PeerAuthentication","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"default","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"mtls":{"mode":"STRICT"}}}
    name: default
    namespace: istio-system
  spec:
    mtls:
  mode: STRICT
```

Here is the service.yaml of my frontend app.

```
capel0068340585:~ semural$ kubectl get svc -n hub-dev
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
oneapihub-ui-dev        ClusterIP   10.254.47.95     <none>        80/TCP     48m

# Source: oneapihub-ui/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-oneapihub-ui
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: oneapihub-ui
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    helm.sh/chart: oneapihub-ui-0.1.0
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

Here is the Gateway and VS that I created in same namepace where microservices are running.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hub-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - foo-bar.example.com
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3

kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hub
spec:
  hosts:
    - foo-bar.example.com
  gateways:
    - hub-gateway
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: oneapihub-ui-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 80
```

Here is the proxy config for ingressgateway

```
$ istioctl proxy-config route istio-ingressgateway-75496c97df-44g6l -n istio-system -o json
[
    {
        "name": "http.80",
        "virtualHosts": [
            {
                "name": "foo-baexample.com:80",
                "domains": [
                    "foo-bar.example.com",
                    "foo-bar.example.com:*"
                ],
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "prefix": "/"
                        },
                        "route": {
                            "cluster": "outbound|80||oneapihub-ui-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local",
                            "timeout": "0s",
                            "retryPolicy": {
                                "retryOn": "connect-failure,refused-stream,unavailable,cancelled,retriable-status-codes",
                                "numRetries": 2,
                                "retryHostPredicate": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "envoy.retry_host_predicates.previous_hosts"
                                    }
                                ],
```

Here are the outputs of istioctl describe pods.

```
    $ istioctl x describe pod oneapihub-api-dev-78fbccf48c-5hb4c -n hub-dev
    Pod: oneapihub-api-dev-78fbccf48c-5hb4c
       Pod Ports: 50004 (oneapihub-api), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    --------------------
    Service: oneapihub-api-dev
       Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 50004
    
    $ istioctl x describe pod oneapihub-auth-dev-7f8998cd69-gzmnm -n hub-dev
    Pod: oneapihub-auth-dev-7f8998cd69-gzmnm
       Pod Ports: 50002 (oneapihub-auth), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    --------------------
    Service: oneapihub-auth-dev
       Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 5000
    
    $ istioctl x describe pod oneapihub-backend-dev-849b4bcd5d-fcm4l -n hub-dev
    Pod: oneapihub-backend-dev-849b4bcd5d-fcm4l
       Pod Ports: 50001 (oneapihub-backend), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    --------------------
    Service: oneapihub-backend-dev
       Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 50001
    $ istioctl x describe pod oneapihub-cronjob-dev-58b64d9c68-lv5bk -n hub-dev
    Pod: oneapihub-cronjob-dev-58b64d9c68-lv5bk
       Pod Ports: 50005 (oneapihub-cronjob), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    --------------------
    Service: oneapihub-cronjob-dev
       Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 50005
    $ istioctl x describe pod oneapihub-mp-dev-74fd6ffc9f-65gh5 -n hub-dev
    Pod: oneapihub-mp-dev-74fd6ffc9f-65gh5
       Pod Ports: 50003 (oneapihub-mp), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    --------------------
    Service: oneapihub-mp-dev
       Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 50003

    $ istioctl x describe pod oneapihub-ui-dev-7fd56f747c-nr5fk -n hub-dev
    Pod: oneapihub-ui-dev-7fd56f747c-nr5fk
       Pod Ports: 3000 (oneapihub-ui), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    --------------------
    Service: oneapihub-ui-dev
       Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 3000
    
    
    Exposed on Ingress Gateway http://53.6.48.168
    VirtualService: hub
       1 HTTP route(s)

$ istioctl x describe pod redis-hub-master-0 -n hub-dev
    Pod: redis-hub-master-0
       Pod Ports: 6379 (redis-hub), 15090 (istio-proxy)
    Suggestion: add 'version' label to pod for Istio telemetry.
    --------------------
    Service: redis-hub-headless
       Port: redis 6379/Redis targets pod port 6379
    --------------------
    Service: redis-hub-master
       Port: redis 6379/Redis targets pod port 6379
```

Here is my destination rule

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: backend-destination-rule
  namespace: hub-dev
spec:
  host: oneapihub-backend-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
      sni: oneapihub-backend-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Do you have destination rules ? else you need to add trafficPolicy:  tls: mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL in the destination rule . Here  is 503 erros causes  https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#503-errors-after-setting-destination-rule

Comment: @ Shay yes, I added as below but still same.. Seems some issue for /config but still I could not able to solve the issue

`tls: mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL sni: oneapihub-backend-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Would you mind adding your destination rules to the question , Else I recommend applying the PeerAuthentication only to hub-dev namespace , not the whole cluster .
Then you can do something   mtls:
    mode: STRICT
  portLevelMtls:
    80:
      mode: DISABLE

Comment: @Shay, I added already.. Current PeerAuthentication apply only hub-dev namespace I also tried

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ? Speaking about disabling pods to communicate between different ns you have to define network policy - read more:  https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675572/how-to-disable-cross-communicate-between-pods-which-are-in-2-different-namespace.

Comment: @Malgorzata,ı posted my answer already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution worked for me to add rewrite:authority to the virtual service

```
  apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: VirtualService
    metadata:
      name: hub
    spec:
      hosts:
        - foo-example.com
      gateways:
        - hub-gateway
      http:
        - route:
          - destination:
              host: oneapihub-ui-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local
              port:
                number: 80
          rewrite:
            authority: oneapihub-backend-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works with Pemissive and you get 503 only for Strict, then the reason for that is you are sending TLS traffic to plain text http port.

I believe the target POD (Upstream) doesn't have sidecar enabled and your actual service running in the POD is accepting plain text http instead of TLS.

To resolve this, you can inject side car in these pods as well, or you will have to make your actual target service mTLS with all proper certificate configurations.

In the end, if you are setting peer authentication as Strict then you can't have plain text traffic in and out of your mesh.

Comment: In addition, I added  outputs of  `istioctl describe` .. I read headless service might be an issue sometimes but not sure its still valid for v1.8 for istio

Comment: the microservices talks with another pod which are running another namespace such as `Vault`, `postgresql` , `ELK` and `Prometheus` but it should be issue I believe.. Should I have to mesh all of them ?